# Inference From TypeTag's

Tags: scala, types

Given the following abstract classes/traits:

```
  sealed trait P2pMessage[T] {
    def value(): T
  }

  trait P2pReq[T] extends P2pMessage[T]

  trait P2pResp[T] extends P2pMessage[T]
```

and given a concrete implementation:

```
case class GetTrainingParamsReq(override val value: String) extends P2pReq[String]

case class GetTrainingParamsResp(override val value: String) extends P2pResp[String]
```

And finally: given a client interface that uses a request/response pair:

```
  def request[U: TypeTag, V: TypeTag](req: P2pReq[U]): P2pResp[V]
```

Then why would the following not be valid (does not compile):

```
  def getTrainingParams(clientName: String): GetTrainingParamsResp = {
    val resp = rpc.request(GetTrainingParamsReq(clientName))
    resp
  }
```

(See screenshot for the error message).

[image]

The type of `P2pResp[Nothing]` as  `Nothing` indicates the `TypeTag` inference from

```
 def request[U: TypeTag, V: TypeTag](req: P2pReq[U]): P2pResp[V]
```

is not working at all. Any ideas why - and how to correct it?

**Update** Responding to a comment:   Notice from this post: `def request[U: TypeTag, V: TypeTag](req: P2pReq[U]): P2pResp[V]`  .  The `U` should be inferred from the type of the input parameter of the invocation of request() and the `V` from the return type.

Comment: How _can_ `V` be inferred? The compiler doesn't have any information to work off of. Should `U` and `V` be the same?

Comment: @m-z From the OP: `def request[U: TypeTag, V: TypeTag](req: P2pReq[U]): P2pResp[V]`  .  The `U` should be inferred from the type of the input parameter of the invocation of request() and the `V` from the return type.

Comment: My question is _how_? If the compiler is given a `P2pReq[U]` with some `U`, how do you tell the compiler what `V` is? The compiler has no theoretical way of proving what `V` is if you provide no evidence.

Comment: Well I am trying to understand just how much *evidence* were required by the compiler. The compiler does have the return type handy - it would be able to get the `V` from there. Now whether the compiler were implemented to support that inference - of that it is not clear to me.   Actually it seems to some extent we were going in circles: is it not clear that the V were available if the compiler wishes to use it?

Comment: Think about it this way: If you have a `P2pReq[U]`, should `request` also return a `P2pResp[U]`? If it instead returns a `P2pResp[V]` where `U != V`, how do you figure out which `V` you get? (`request` must know). If `V` cannot be determined at compile time, then `request` probably returns a `P2pResp[_]`, because you don't know what it is until run time.. but by then it is too late to produce a `TypeTag`.

Comment: But the return type *is* declared:  `GetTrainingParamsResp` - which is a *concretized* type of `P2pResp[String]`.  Both the return type and the return Type parameter are thus known  at compile time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala type inference works from top to bottom. So when type-checking `val resp = rpc.request(GetTrainingParamsReq(clientName))`, the compiler doesn't use information from below that `resp` will be used as the return value and must have type `GetTrainingParamsResp`.

Annotating the expected type `val resp: P2pResp[String]` would allow the compiler to infer `V`. But now it won't compile for a different reason: you only have a `P2pResp[String]`, but need a `GetTrainingParamsResp`. And annotating `val resp: GetTrainingParamsResp` makes no sense because it's a subtype of the return type instead of the opposite, just as

```
def foo(): Object = ""
val resp: String = foo()
```

makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, i'll buy this explanation.